# How to register user in devise with active record association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I'm doing experiment using rails and devise_token_auth for authentication. I successfully create a new user for devise_token_auth. I already search this in google or here in this forum but I can't find a solid documention on how going to do it. But if you provide me link. It will more appreciated for a new rails developer to study it. I'm trying to add a profiles with users. In user table I add reference for profile and here is the result.

[image]

as you can see there is `profile_id` added in my user table. In my user model, I have this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User 

  belongs_to :profile
end
```

and also in my profile model. I have this

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :user
end
```

in my application_controller.rb. I have this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    #protect_from_forgery with: :exception 

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        registration_params = [ :name, :city, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile => [:address]]
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: registration_params)
    end
end
```

I try to use postman for register a user to devise. I have these params to send

```
{
    "name": "rayn",
    "email": "helloworld.232910@gmail.com",
    "password": "sample123",
    "password_confirmation": "sample123",
    "city": "green",
    "profile": {
        "address": "address here"
    },
    "confirm_success_url": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

but when i submit this i got these error

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Profile(#70239077093620) expected, got {\"address\"=>\"address here\"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#47165751411560)>",
    "traces": {
```

I don't know if my model is correct. I just want to add profile every each user. Correct me for what I did in my code. How can I register a user with profile added?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing `accepts_nested_attribute` and so `active_record` is not able to follow what to do with this object - Assuming, there's a column address in `Profile`:

```
# user.rb
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Comment: I already add that code. Still the same error issue i got. Do i need to create registration controller? Sorry for late rply